# Looping through PSObject from JSON response

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I am running Invoke-RestMethod to get a response from an API.  That response is in JSON format and I am trying to figure out how to get access to the individual properties in my Powershell code.

Given these two lines:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $paymentJournalUri -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host $response
```

my output looks like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context":  "https://api....yments",
    "value":  [
                  {
                      "@odata.etag":  "W/\"JzI....Dsn\"",
                      "id":  "b86ac....8fab",
                      "journalId":  "59....b3ca",
                      "journalDisplayName":  "EFT",
                      "lineNumber":  30000,
                      "vendorId":  "a4c...552",
                      ...
```

So how can I loop over the 'value' array and get access to each of those properties?

I have tried something like this:

```
$PSObj = $response | ConvertTo-Json

#Write-Host $PSObj

$PSObj.value | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.journalDisplayName
}
```

Comment: Start by not using `ConvertTo-Json` so you can actually deal with an object instead of a string :)

Comment: `$response.value | ForEach-Object { ... }` or `foreach( $curValue in $response.value ) { ... }`